# Visual Studio Code Mocha ProblemMatcher

Tags: mocha.js, visual-studio-code

I'm searching for the configuration of a problem matcher for Mocha in Visual Studio Code. Problem matchers inspect the terminal output for errors and add them in the Problems view.

Problem matchers in VS Code are described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_processing-task-output-with-problem-matchers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like all built-in reporters describe the error with variable number of lines. And building vscode problem matcher for such kind of reporting is not supported - multiline support is extremely limited.

But we can build our own reporter with whatever format we like and then match on it with ease!

Here is a simple reporter which extends default Spec reporter with outputting errors with `$tsc-watch` matcher compatible format:

```
// my-reporter.js
var StackTraceParser = require('stacktrace-parser');
var path = require('path');
var mocha = require('mocha');
module.exports = MyReporter;

function MyReporter(runner) {
  mocha.reporters.Spec.call(this, runner);

  runner.on('fail', function(test, err){
    var lines = StackTraceParser.parse(err.stack)
    // we are only interested in the place in the test which originated the error
    var line = lines.find(line => line.file.startsWith('test'))
    if (line) {
      console.log(`${line.file}(${line.lineNumber},${line.column}): error TS0000: ${err.message.split('\n')[0]}`)
    }
  });

}

// To have this reporter "extend" a built-in reporter uncomment the     following line:
mocha.utils.inherits(MyReporter, mocha.reporters.Spec);
```

Add command to `scripts` section in `package.json`:

```
"test": "mocha --reporter my-reporter.js"
```

You then add to your `tasks.json`:

```
{
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "test",
  "problemMatcher": [
    {
      "applyTo": "allDocuments",
      "fileLocation": "relative",
      "base": "$tsc-watch",
      "source": "mocha"
    }
  ],
  "group": {
    "kind": "test",
    "isDefault": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I get `Error: Cannot find module 'stacktrace-parser'`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I fixed the above by including a newer version of Mocha.